# Curity identity service is Listening on 0.0.0.0:6749 on my macOS, but browser is giving ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Tags: macos, curity

se.curity.identityserver.jetty.AppServer.AdminApiServerLifecycleManager - Listening on 0.0.0.0:6749

*❯ netstat -an | grep LISTEN*

tcp46      0      0  *.6749                 *.*                    LISTEN

[browser response screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKj8C.png)
{app-server-AdminApiServerLifecycleManager}

is there any way to change curity server configuration and listen at 127.0.0.1:6749, (instead of 0.0.0.0:6749)?

Answer (score 2):

listening on `0.0.0.0` makes the server listen on any IP that will direct you to your mac. Make sure also to explicitly use HTTPS. Try entering this address to open the admin UI:

`https://127.0.0.1:6749/admin`